how to sing in tune when you have to sing a cappella without reference notes?
I learned that when an instrument plays a note (like pressing the piano keys) to reproduce them by ear at the same time as I play them
but without anything a capella we comment?
like there I don't have an instrument at hand and I have to know how to sing
how do I do it like that?
I may have a score but I can't visually see what I'm sending to the voice

You're asking how to find your starting pitch without an external reference? That's not something that would normally be expected of a singer, is there a reason you need to do it?

or are you saying you wouldn't be able to sing a capella even if you were given the starting note, and it was just the rest of the notes that were unaccompanied?

Having absolute ('perfect') pitch is probably the only way.
Although a lot of singers who've sung particular songs many times will be able to pitch within a tone - and with no reference notes played, who's to know..?
This is a question that I've often thought about - just about every instrument will have finger position/embouchure to produce a certain pitch, but not human voice. Even when given a pitch to copy, how does it know..? +1 for that.
Best, for accuracy, to carry some sort of tuning apparatus around if you're that concerned, like a tuning fork, electronic tuner, small instrument?

Singing does mean actually making physical movements within your body, so as long as we don't care too precisely about accuracy, singers probably get used to some of the sensations, especially e.g. if they sing the same song very often.

@AndyBonner - which is what I intimated. But rarely do they get it spot on.

I have a song that I normally play in A, but a while ago I decided I wanted to perform it in E for once instead. It was a pain to rehearse. I kept starting wrong, on a pitch that I wouldn't know how precisely it matched the usual A, but definitely wasn't in tune with the E that I was playing. (I accompany myself on a guitar.) Did make it in time, and it was actually fun to do it sounding like a real man, but next time I feel like messing with the established key of a song, I'll think twice, it's more work than I thought. Mostly I don't even notice transposition, but when it's my own song...

@Divizna - did you start it acapella? half an octave is a big difference, even for a song with a small range.

@Tim Of course not! I always put in a few bars on the guitar as a short intro to calibrate myself on. I wouldn't trust myself to hit it right if I started singing first. But here I had to play the song a number of times until I got used to the change. (And you're right it was a big difference. In A the song is very comfortable to sing. In E I was kinda scraping the bottom at times - but then I could throw in a chorus an octave higher and call it "boys' troop singing", heh.)

@Divizna - it's hoped that the bar before the vox starts will be a bar of V on the guitar...

@Tim Is it? Huh. My most common choice is the tonic (as was in this case), but more generally, I treat it as a creative choice, like the rest of the tune. Never heard of such practical consideration. Might explain why I had such difficulty switching, considering E just so happens to be the fifth of A...

@Divizna - The dominant 7th (E7) would be easier to guide the vox into key A.

@Tim Good thing I at least wasn't playing that, then, when I needed to sing in E.

@Divizna - true - B7 would be an option then.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
